# Edge throwing 404 for bootstrap scss files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, asp.net-core-mvc, bower, microsoft-edge

I am trying to build a web app using asp.net core. I added bootstrap 3.3.7 using bower, but when I run the app on edge, it throws a bunch of 404's for missing sass files. (See attachment). I haven't worked with bower before, so just wanted to add that, I am adding the dependencies manually in the bower.json file using ~. The files are downloaded into the lib folder, and I referenced the min files under dist folder.

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the following Bootstrap CSS, which is used for CSS preprocessor, such as Sass, Less, or Stylus.

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap-grid.css.map */
```

I have my own custom CSS file that is downloaded after the Bootstrap CSS files, and I added the following code to the end of my custom CSS file to stop Bootstrap mapping files from being downloaded:

```
/* This is to stop CSS preprocessor, such as Sass, Less, or Stylus, from downloading the bootstrap map file. */
/*# sourceMappingURL= */
```

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142485/why-is-bootstrap-trying-to-load-less-files-in-edge ?